# How do I classify data by their words in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am a student whose trying to get familiar with `MongoDB`.

I am currently making a program in `Java` that gets tweets using twitter stream and stores those tweets into db using `MongoDB`.

I have done up to saving the tweets to `MongoDB` and now I want to classify those tweets by the words.

**Like this:**

Lets say:

```
Tweet1 = " I am A" 
Tweet2 = "I am B"
```

And what I want to do is when I classify them somehow, I want it to look like this:

```
I :  Tweet1, Tweet2
Am : Tweet1, Tweet2
A : Tweet1
B : Tweet2
```

Do I have to use index for this? It doesn't matter whether it is actually changing the db or just searching through index. I just want my outcome to look like this.

It's my first time working with databases so all these index and the db things are really confusing for me.

It will be great if anyone can provide me some hints for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **inverted** index. Given a word, you want to quickly look up the tweets that contain it. Below is example `Java` code that does this. At the point where the two sample tweets are written, you would include code to pull them from `MongoDB`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SimpleInvertedIndex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //inverted index
        Map<String, LinkedList<String>> index = new TreeMap<>();

        //tweets data
        Map<String, String> tweets = new HashMap<>();

        //Sample tweets
        tweets.put("Tweet1", " I am A");
        tweets.put("Tweet2", "I am B");

        //build the inverted index
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tweets.entrySet()) {
            String tweetId = entry.getKey();
            String[] values = entry.getValue().trim().split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                index.putIfAbsent(values[i], new LinkedList<>());
                LinkedList<String> updatedList = index.get(values[i]);
                updatedList.add(tweetId);
                index.put(values[i], updatedList);
            }
        }

        //verify by printing out
        for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<String>> entry : index.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " : ");
            System.out.print(entry.getValue());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A  : [Tweet1]
B  : [Tweet2]
I  : [Tweet2, Tweet1]
am : [Tweet2, Tweet1]
```

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for your help! I tried your code before combining it to my code and I got one little error. I tried googling but I couldn't find suitable answer. I haven't used hashmap before so its a bit confusing..
index.putIfAbsent(values[i], new LinkedList<>());
I got a error here, saying "The method putifAbsent(String, LinkedList<Object>) is undefined for the type Map<String,LinkedList<String>>"
Would you be able to help? Thanks

Comment: putIfAbsent() is available in Java 8. It seems you are using Java 7.  Is that so?

Comment: Assuming you have Java 7, replace the putIfAbsent() line with this: if (!index.containsKey(values[i])) { index.put(values[i], new LinkedList<>()); }

Comment: I've installed java-8-oracle, and if eclipse says:
"java.runtime.version=1.8.0_171-b11"
It means its running on JAVA8 right?

Comment: Oh! I fixed it!. I've put new LinkedList<String>()); and the code worked fine!
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Sure. By the way, the java.runtime.version is indicating the JRE. You need JDK 8 to compile Java 8 code. In Eclipse, the JDK is indicated at About -> Installation Details -> Configuration -> -vm (line under it)

Comment: Thanks! Ill check!